# dynamic allocation of array of struct pointers

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array of struct in another struct 
here is the code segment

I don't get any syntax errors but I get segmentation fault once I try to enter str1

could someone explain why is there a segmentation fault, and what happens in memory in the dynamic allocation in such situation

```
struct A {
   string str1;
   string str2;
}

struct B {
   int count;
   A* A_array;
}


void GetB (B** b)
{

 *b = (B*) malloc(1*sizeof(B));
 cout << "Enter count";
 cin >> (**b).count;
 (**b).A_array = (A*) malloc((**b).count*sizeof(A));
 cout << "Enter str1";
 cin >> (**b).A_array[0].str1;
 cout << "Enter str2";
 cin >> (**b).A_array[0].str2;

}

int main(){
   B* b;
   GetB(&b);
}
```

Comment: what a horrible mix of C and C++

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `malloc` instead of `new`? Generally, if you're programming in C++, you want to actually use C++.

Comment: Start by deciding whether you're you're writing C or C++. If you're writing C, don't use `cin` or `cout` and don't cast the return from `malloc`. If you're writing C++, don't use `malloc` at all, and use `std::vector` instead of your home-rolled imitation.

Comment: sorry about that I am using c++ but I my problem is with the malloc 
so I thought people with c or cpp experience can help with it that is why I but both on the tags

Comment: I'll repeat: if you're using C++, don't use malloc. When writing C++, it's best to forget that it exists at all.

Comment: -1 because it doesn’t compile.

Comment: Is this some legacy code you're working with ? I haven't seen "factory functions" written in this way for many, many years ... the perpetrators of atrocities like `(**b)` seem to have mostly died in the nineties :)

Comment: @FrankH. I learned C and used it for a short while (my teacher was an old man) and now I am learning c++ so this is my mix understanding between the two, If there is a young way to do it please let me know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting a crash is because `string str1;` `string str2;` do not get constructed properly.

And they are not constructed properly because `malloc` only allocates memory and doesn't call the constructors.

Which is what operator `new` is for in C++.

Therefore, as highlighted in comments:

1. Never ever use `malloc` to allocate non-POD objects.
2. Even better, never use `malloc` in c++ at all.
3. And better still, never ever use manually allocated arrays, use `std::vector` instead

Comment: +1 for that last paragraph (well, and the whole answer as well).

Comment: I replaced the `malloc` with `new` in both lines and it worked

Comment: @Roola But you do understand that changing those two `malloc`s to `new`s is only a quick and dirty fix for your code and that there are more and larger issues to it? You'll make it a lot easier for your future self if you learn *now* how to do things the C++ way instead of continuing with your current style until you hit a project complex enough where it fails.

Comment: @us2012 thank you for your comment, could you tell me what exactly are you refereeing to? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Roola For example: Your method that produces a `B` still has signature `void GetB (B** b)` when it could simply be `B GetB()` avoiding the pointers entirely. You are still using `A*` instead of `vector<A>`. You may want to explore whether your classes should have constructors, or whether their members should be private.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comments, this would be an equivalent of your current program using some more idiomatic C++. I have deliberately kept the structure as close to your original as possible, but there are of course other issues to think about, like whether your classes should have constructors or private members.

```
struct A {
   string str1;
   string str2;
};

struct B {
   int count;
   vector<A> A_vec;
};

B GetB ()
{
   B myB;
   cout << "Enter count";
   cin >> myB.count;
   A a;
   cout << "Enter str1";
   cin >> a.str1;
   cout << "Enter str2";
   cin >> a.str2;
   myB.A_vec.push_back(a);
   return myB;
}

int main(){
   B b(GetB());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. I noticed that you didn't use pointers, do you recommend staying away from pointers in c++

Comment: @Roola That would be too general. Pointers are not inherently bad, and some things (implementing trees or linked lists) simply require pointers! In my opinion, a reasonable guideline is: Don't use raw pointers where ownership of an object is implied. But that will likely not mean a lot to you at this point, so really, you need to get a good and modern book on C++ and learn this stuff from scratch.